# matplotlib 3dbars: trouble with axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot bars each with a base at an x,y coordinate and a height equal to a z value. The code below doesn't seem to capture my x-axis properly and I'm not sure why.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = [0.0245, 0.015, 0.0245, 0.0285, 0.0245, 0.0245]
y = [0.0024, 0.0075, 0.0095, 0.01, 0.008, 0.0018]
z = [11.71, 2.09, 2.49, 2.05, 2.72, 22.55]

ax.bar(x, y, z, zdir='z', color='g', alpha=.8)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the arguments, you say you want height equal to z value, but you are passing in y as the height of the bars.  Is this better, using `bar3d`?

[image]

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = [0.0245, 0.015, 0.0245, 0.0285, 0.0245, 0.0245]
y = [0.0024, 0.0075, 0.0095, 0.01, 0.008, 0.0018]
z = [11.71, 2.09, 2.49, 2.05, 2.72, 22.55]

ax.bar3d(x, y, [0]*6, 0.001, 0.001, z)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```